# For loop doesn't stop at zero index

Tags: c++, loops

Sorry for a probably stupid question.
My loop does not stop at 0 and I have no idea why.

This loop will stop at i = 1

```
for (unsigned int i = 3 ; i > 0 ; i--)
```

Whereas this will stop at i =   4294967295 instead

```
for (unsigned int i = 3 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

Why? Do I miss anything?

Comment: You used an `unsigned int`, which can’t be less than zero. Use an `int`.

Comment: I avoid backwards for loops wherever possible. If you want to iterate backwards, for example, try using reverse iterators.

Comment: @NeilKirk 'reverse' do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide more of the code you're using to test this?

Comment: _will stop at `i = 4294967295`_ Hm.., are you sure that the second loop ever stops?

Comment: @Steephen Sorry yes I meant reverse.

Comment: Agreed with @NeilKirk. Every loop should go forward, even the ones that go backward: `for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) { const unsigned int ri = 3 - i - 1; /* use ri */ }`

Comment: @KerrekSB *Every loop should go forward, even the ones that go backward* I like that!

Comment: @KerrekSB IMHO if it actually goes backwards, it should look like it goes backwards. Camouflaging it as a forward iteration for style's sake would seem to be counter to actual code clarity.

Comment: @greggo: The reason is that I think of loops as implementation details, and the underlying, more profound concept is that of a *range*. So in the more abstract view, there's always just "iteration over a range", just one single concept. It's only the details of the range that change. In the example I gave above, the detail is that the range is the "reverse" of an existing range, and the computed index `ri` expresses this underlying range operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact this `i >= 0` for unsigned int is always true. So you cannot use it as loop invariant.

Use this instead:

```
for (unsigned int i = 4 ; i-- > 0 ;)
  println(i);
```

it will print 3,2,1,0

Comment: While this looks weird to people who haven't seen it before, I believe it to be the standard way to do a reverse loop iteration (especially with unsigned index type).

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop iterates until the break condition evaluates to `false`.

In your case the loop will repeatedly check:
is `i>0` (`i>=0` respectively) `true`? If so, execute body and decrement `i`, else skip the loop-body.

Your first loop will at some point reach `i=1`. `i>0` will evaluate to `true`. The body will be executed, `i` will be decremented. `i` will then be 0. Hence `i>0` will evaluate to `false` and the body will not be executed and you will break out of the loop.

Your second loop will not stop (tested with g++). Why? Your `i` will reach 0. `i>=0` will evaluate to true. The body will be executed, `i` will be decremented. But since you are using an `unsigned int` this will then assign 4294967295 to `i`.  Since `4294967295>=0`, the loop will continue, reach 0 again and again assign 4294967295 to `i` thus executing indefinitely.

This happens since an unsigned int represents 0 as all 0s in binary and subtracting 1 from it will yield all 1s which is interpreted as 4294967295.

How to avoid the problem? As mentioned in the comments a simple way out of it would be to use an `int` instead of an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Unsigned integers do not overflow in C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB : just tried. unsigned int x=4294967295. x+1 will be 0.

Comment: @KerrekSB the C++ behaviour is the same as C, it's a modulo operation.

Comment: @dingalapadum: I understand that. But it's not called "overflow". Overflow is generally a thing that results in undefined behaviour. The wrapping around is in fact not going "over" at all, but rather "back to the beginning".

Comment: Hm I always thought it was called overflow, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ok. I removed the part on 'overflow'. Still, I wouldn't call it "back to the beginning", but rather wrapping around. It goes "over" in the sense that by adding 1 you get all 0s and the 1 in the beginning which doesn't fit into the pattern (The carry-bit gets dropped out).

Comment: @NeilKirk: See the footnote in 3.9.1/4: "unsigned arithmetic does not overflow"